# Notation for when x=?, y=?

Tags: notation

Is there notation for what is essentially when, for the situation, for example:

In the situation when x is 2, y is 21t (edited)

Sorry for being brief; if it lacks clarity, please leave a comment and I will amend it

Edit:

It's to keep my math notes tidy when I'm asked to write the acceleration when time is 0; I have to write this as words though I feel it's sloppy and I'm wondering if there's notation for this situation

Comment: ${x\choose y}={5\choose0}+t{0\choose1}$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$??

Other than that I have no idea what you are on about.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Sorry, it's hard to explain; in the situation when x = 7, y = 21t (just another example; I hope it's clearer)

Comment: What is your *real* problem? What are you hoping to accomplish here?

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: If $\mathbf a(t)$ is the function that gives the acceleration at time $t$... then $\mathbf a(0)$ suffices, no?

Comment: @J.M. But I then went on to do the say when the velocity was 0; sorry I didn't explain that

Comment: In short, you haven't yet posted your ***real*** problem. Could you explain in much detail what you really want to do here, in the question body?

Comment: Writing things in words is _not at all_ sloppy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y(x)|_{x=5}=21t$$ should do.

Answer (score 2):

$(x,y) = (5,21t)$?

Hope that helps,